How do I install Google Chrome on Ubuntu 24.04?
I have used Google Chrome with many versions of Ubuntu.  I recently installed Ubuntu 24.04 on a laptop.  Subsequently I downloaded a Chrome Deb package from Google and installed it. When I then tried to launch Chrome it would not start.  No resons given by the system. It just fails. What is going on?

start from command line; look if there is an  error and if it does see if there is a fix.

does this Ubuntu Handbook resource help answer your question? Take note of the instructions how to uninstall (at the end) then re-install it following the instructions carefully.

I have a similar problem since update to 24.04:  => google-chrome [0619/174304.681868:ERROR:elf_dynamic_array_reader.h(64)] tag not found Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

I don't like using snap but when google-chrome was unusable I used chromium snap.

If there is any issue preventing the GUI from loading, you can try starting the google-chrome application from terminal:
These simpler instructions worked for me:

wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

Now you can use dpkg to install Chrome from the downloaded DEB file:

sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

Running the application:

google-chrome

Reference: https://itsfoss.com/install-chrome-ubuntu/

I faced the same problem, and this answer works. I think you should consider accepting it.

Installed this way, I always get "Reinstall chrome" warning every now and then as it doesn't update automatically.

I had the same problem and these steps helped me:

When I tried to run google-chrome in terminal I saw the error:
The profile appears to be in use by another Google Chrome process on another computer. Chrome has locked the profile so that it doesn't get corrupted. If you are sure no other processes are using this profile, you can unlock the profile and relaunch Chrome.

After that checked output of:
hostnamectl
stat ~/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock

In my case the problem was solved  after  removing the config file  /home/Link/.config/google-chrome/SingletonLock


I found solving here:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=294107

My answer is a variation of the one @prusswan gave. Kudos there.

Make sure the system is up-to-date.

~# apt update
~# apt upgrade


Make sure wget is installed (and install it if it's not).

~# wget --version


Use wget to fetch the latest google-chrome package (into the current directory).

~# wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb


Attempt to run dpkg, which failed due to missing dependencies. (This is where using apt install would be preferred to avoid dependency hell.)

~# dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package google-chrome-stable.
(Reading database ... 171077 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking google-chrome-stable (130.0.6723.91-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:
 google-chrome-stable depends on fonts-liberation; however:
  Package fonts-liberation is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package google-chrome-stable (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.12.0-4build2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable


Use apt to fix the borked install.

~# apt --fix-broken install
<... snip ...>
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  fonts-liberation fonts-liberation-sans-narrow
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fonts-liberation fonts-liberation-sans-narrow
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 1,800 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,894 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
<... snip ...>
Selecting previously unselected package fonts-liberation.
(Reading database ... 171195 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../fonts-liberation_1%3a2.1.5-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking fonts-liberation (1:2.1.5-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package fonts-liberation-sans-narrow.
Preparing to unpack .../fonts-liberation-sans-narrow_1%3a1.07.6-4_all.deb ...
Unpacking fonts-liberation-sans-narrow (1:1.07.6-4) ...
Setting up fonts-liberation (1:2.1.5-3) ...
Setting up fonts-liberation-sans-narrow (1:1.07.6-4) ...
Setting up google-chrome-stable (130.0.6723.91-1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable to provide /usr/bin/x-www-browser (x-www-browser) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable to provide /usr/bin/gnome-www-browser (gnome-www-browser) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable to provide /usr/bin/google-chrome (google-chrome) in auto mode
Processing triggers for fontconfig (2.15.0-1.1ubuntu2) ...
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed


Run dpkg again.

~# dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 171224 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking google-chrome-stable (130.0.6723.91-1) over (130.0.6723.91-1) ...
Setting up google-chrome-stable (130.0.6723.91-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.12.0-4build2) ...


View what's left behind.

~# cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

~# /etc/apt/sources.list.d# ll
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov  2 11:14 ./
drwxr-xr-x 9 root root 4096 Oct 31 13:59 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  190 Nov  2 10:52 google-chrome.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  386 Oct 31 13:59 ubuntu.sources
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2552 Aug 27 10:21 ubuntu.sources.curtin.orig

~# /etc/apt/sources.list.d# more google-chrome.list
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main

~# /etc/apt/sources.list.d# which google-chrome
/usr/bin/google-chrome

~# /etc/apt/sources.list.d# ll `which google-chrome`
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Oct 28 20:19 /usr/bin/google-chrome -> /etc/alternatives/google-chrome*

~# /etc/apt/sources.list.d# ll /etc/alternatives/google-chrome
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Oct 28 20:19 /etc/alternatives/google-chrome -> /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable*

~# /etc/apt/sources.list.d# ll /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Oct 28 20:19 /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable -> /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome*

~# /etc/apt/sources.list.d# ll /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1585 Oct 28 20:19 /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome*

~# /etc/apt/sources.list.d# ll /opt/google/chrome/
total 292732
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root      4096 Nov  2 10:52 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root      4096 Nov  2 10:50 ../
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 249363672 Oct 28 20:19 chrome*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    824033 Oct 28 20:19 chrome_100_percent.pak
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1470792 Oct 28 20:19 chrome_200_percent.pak
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   2444992 Oct 28 20:19 chrome_crashpad_handler*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   4331216 Oct 28 20:19 chrome-management-service*
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root    208000 Oct 28 20:19 chrome-sandbox*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         7 Oct 28 20:19 CHROME_VERSION_EXTRA
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      4096 Nov  2 10:52 cron/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       482 Oct 28 20:19 default-app-block
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      4096 Nov  2 10:52 default_apps/
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      1585 Oct 28 20:19 google-chrome*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  10468208 Oct 28 20:19 icudtl.dat
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    240384 Oct 28 20:19 libEGL.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   6976728 Oct 28 20:19 libGLESv2.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   7691144 Oct 28 20:19 liboptimization_guide_internal.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     26688 Oct 28 20:19 libqt5_shim.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     28960 Oct 28 20:19 libqt6_shim.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4683512 Oct 28 20:19 libvk_swiftshader.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    562344 Oct 28 20:19 libvulkan.so.1
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      4096 Nov  2 10:52 locales/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      4096 Nov  2 10:52 MEIPreload/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      4096 Nov  2 10:52 PrivacySandboxAttestationsPreloaded/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     10577 Oct 28 20:19 product_logo_128.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       787 Oct 28 20:19 product_logo_16.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      1281 Oct 28 20:19 product_logo_24.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     38037 Oct 28 20:19 product_logo_256.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      1810 Oct 28 20:19 product_logo_32.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      7611 Oct 28 20:19 product_logo_32.xpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      3095 Oct 28 20:19 product_logo_48.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      4557 Oct 28 20:19 product_logo_64.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   9505137 Oct 28 20:19 resources.pak
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    687473 Oct 28 20:19 v8_context_snapshot.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       107 Oct 28 20:19 vk_swiftshader_icd.json
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root      4096 Nov  2 10:52 WidevineCdm/
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     37394 Oct 28 20:19 xdg-mime*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     33273 Oct 28 20:19 xdg-settings*


Interesting symbolic link path. It appears that dpkg set up the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list so that future updates should work with apt.
